# Cómo pasar una celda datagridview a textbox

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

Tengo algunos días tratando de pasar un valor de un datagridview a un textbox.

Tengo un datagridview con 2 columnas:
columnaID= 1,2,3
columnaValor= azul, verde, rojo

Cómo puedo hacer para que al escribir 1 en el textbox, se pase el text azul. ó si escribo 2 se pase el texto verde.

Puedo pasar datos del datagridview a textboxes pero en el evento doble clic, pero lo anterior no he logrado hacerlo.

Comment: Se me pasó comentar que son muchos datos, los que puse son solo ejemplos, podría hacerlo manualmente pero sería un código muy largo. Necesito escribir un id en el textbox y pasar el valor de ese ID al textbox

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es extraer la información de la grid con el evento "KeyDown" del textbox cuando oprimas la tecla enter, esto puede hacerse de muchas maneras en este ejemplo lo hice recorriendo la grid.

Suponiendo que tu Grid la columna 0 = ID y la columna 1 = Descripcion

Tendrías que escribir el ID en el textbox, oprimir enter y voila la descripcion se colocara en el mismo textbox.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If (rw.Cells(0).Value = TextBox1.Text) Then
                TextBox1.Text = rw.Cells(1).Value
            End If
        Next
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Saludos!